# Getting undefined from .env file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, environment-variables

After I created the .env in the root of the React folder

```
REACT_APP_API_KEY=gzomlK5CKLiaIWS....
```

I also downloaded the .env NPM library

I still got undefined in the API file, what I am missing

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import "./Api.scss";
require("dotenv").config();
console.log(process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY);
```

Comment: Are you using Create React App in this project?

Comment: yes using create react app

Answer (score 0):

I totally forgot to restart the terminal, it is working now.
I think restarting the terminal was the issue.